# Wild card in xcode

Tags: ios

I want to separate a string by component and put it in an array
like

```
tagArray=[MyString componentsSeparatedByString:@"[Result]"];
```

problem is the `tag [Result]` has some values inside it eg `[Result 0-1]` how can i use wild cards to separate component by Result tag irrespective of the varying values.
 Thanks

Comment: new to x code reading about it

Comment: Have a look at this cheat sheet too http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSString  also tell us if you still couldn't make it work, post your code ...

Comment: Ali iam trying to parse a pgn file (programming gaming notation).

Comment: retagged; not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ARC you should do it like this:

```
NSError * error = nil;
__unsafe_unretained NSMutableString * authorsaddresses = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
NSRegularExpression * regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^SOMEREGEX" options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:response options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [response length]) 
                         usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult * result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL * stop) {
                             [authorsaddresses appendString:response];
                         }];
```